# How to properly update a table in the user computer?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I have a conceptual doubt related to updating fields in a database.

I have developed a **Qt** (**C++**) application that uses **SQLite** to store data. The **SQLite** file (.db) is stored in the user computer. The file is automatically created when the user opens the application for the first time.

The problem is that I need to update one table in that database. I can do it using the `ALTER TABLE` command, but how can I properly update the table in the database that is allocated in the user computer?

Do I need to create a function that checks if the table doesn't have the fields that I want and then runs the `ALTER TABLE` command or there is some other easy/correct way to to this?

Comment: How do you distribute the application?  If you use a updater to update the application then you can have the updater check for the presence of the column and update the DB as needed.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver. Unfortunately, I don't have an updater and the application (.exe) is distributed by a link sent by e-mail. However, I can check for the presence of the column directly on the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more general solution may be to use a version number entry in the DB and centralise changes based on this. If you don't have it, you can create it with this update. At least I think it becomes clearer in the code and you have a single point for future modifications:

```
void update_database_to_current_version() {
  const int version = current_db_version(); // returns 1 if version is not found

  if (version < 2) { // since version 2 table XYZ has new structure, match here
      // 'ALTER TABLE' ...
  }

  // if (version < N) // DB changes starting in version N
  // ...

  update_db_version_to_newest();
}
```

On the other hand, as far as I now, you can run the `ALTER TABLE` several times without affecting the table, so that may be a quicker option if you prefer.

Comment: Typically what you do is a "version ladder", a function with all the single update steps to the each next version; so that wouldn't be a `switch`, but a series of `if`, with each step updating the version to the next one.

Comment: Right! I was just drawing my idea... I'm updating the answer with this suggestion!

Comment: Thank you very much @cbuchart, it seems to be a great solution for my problem. I don't have a version number entry in the DB but I will search how to use this on **SQLite**.

Comment: Android uses [PRAGMA user_version](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_user_version) for this, but you could just as well create a separate table.

Comment: @cbuchart This is a case where using a transaction is important; you'd never want to have a partial update.

Comment: @CL. that's true, the whole update must be done at once, atomically. I'm not very fluent with SQL, maybe you can help with that part?

Comment: Good point @CL. I will certainly use a transaction to avoid inconsistency.